# Disable input field if is already filled Javascript (Sudoku)

Tags: javascript

I am bulding a Sudoku Solver. All fields of the sudoku can be edited. When the user clicks on "New Sudoku" some of those fields are filled with numbers. At the moment these "filled" fields can still be edited by the user. I want them to be disabled so that the number of the "filled" fields can not be changed.
I am a beginner and grateful for any help :)

[My sudoku so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKjEz.png)

```
function createField(event) {
    let gridCont;
    let fieldCont;
    let sudokuBox = document.getElementById("sudokuBox");
    gridCont = document.createElement("div");
    gridCont.classList.add("grid-cont");
    for(row=1; row<=9; row++) {
        fieldCont = document.createElement("div") //The 3x3 grid
        fieldCont.classList.add("field-cont");
        fieldCont.classList.add("indexBig"); //gives index (3x3)
        for(col=1; col<=9; col++) { 
            let dataCell = document.createElement("input")
            dataCell.classList.add("sudoku-cell");
            dataCell.classList.add("data-cell");
            dataCell.classList.add("indexSmall"); 
            fieldCont.appendChild(dataCell);
         }   
        gridCont.appendChild(fieldCont);
    }
    sudokuBox.appendChild(gridCont);    
}

function populateSudoku(JObject){
    let fill = document.querySelectorAll(".indexBig");
    JObject.sudokuJSON.forEach((bigCellEl, i)=> { 
        bigCellEl.forEach((cellNumb, j)=> { 
            if(cellNumb > 0){
                fill[i].children[j].value=cellNumb; 
                //cellNumb.disabled = true; My first idea, but it doesn't work...**
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Add a custom class for pre-filled boxes and disable input using CSS. It would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach event.preventDefault() to onkeydown for all the generated inputs:

```js
    const createNew = () => {
      //irrelevant 
      let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
      let random = Math.floor(inputs.length * Math.random());
      let input = inputs[random]
      input.value = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
      
      //attach prevent default on keydown
      input.onkeydown = (event) => event.preventDefault();
    }
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text"/>
<button onclick="createNew()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `readonly` property:

```
fill[i].children[j].readonly = true;
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved it by disabling input in css. But readonly seems to work as well.